# Smoke + water from exhaust while starting MM 540

Tags: jeep, diesel

**Vehicle** - Mahindra and Mahindra MM540 (1997)
**Engine**  - Mahindra and Mahindra 540 1.9 peugeot Engine (inline-4)
**Miles**   - ~75000 miles

When I start my jeep, smoke and oily water comes out through exhaust.

Sometimes the jeep wont start and it seems like there's no battery charge. If I try after few minutes, it will start.

What could be the issue here? How should I go about diagnosing it?

Comment: When you say smoke, what color is the smoke? Is there a sweet aroma to the exhaust? What engine is in the vehicle? (Inline-4 I'm assuming?) A video of the no start situation would help tremendously. If you pull a spark plug, what does it look like (picture here would do wonders as well). How many miles on it? Anything else you can think of?

Comment: it is a Mahindra all wheel drive vehicle. smoke color is black itself. there isn't any sweet aroma. Engine is Mahindra and Mahindra 540 1.9 peugeot Engine (inline-4). Around 75000 miles done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how the Mahindra fires, but would suggest that your glow plugs are bad in your diesel engine. I'm not sure about the water, though. This could be an internal leak, but could also just be the byproduct of combustion.